# Is the preposition 'to' optional in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, verbs, subordinate-clauses

We can propose something to someone. Again, if we propose to someone, we usually give the proposal for marriage. But I am confused when 'propose' is used with an object and a that-clause. In that case, can we use preposition 'to' between the verb 'propose' & the object?

I have found the following sentence :

> He proposed me that we should go there.

Can it be written in the following way?

> He proposed **to** me that we should go there.

Is the preposition 'to' optional here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20251/proposed-her-vs-proposed-to-her#:~:text=The%20verb%20propose%20means%20%22suggesting,%27offering%20her%20some%20designation%27.

Comment: No. See the question minutely. It's NOT duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

"To" is required.
The word "tell" is ditransitive, so you could say
*He told me that we should go there.*
There, "me" is the indirect object and the clause "that we should go there"  is the direct object.

But "propose" isn't ditransitive. In your example, the clause "that we should go there" is the direct object. "Propose" can't take an indirect object, so "to" is required to mark the recipient of the proposal.

Comment: Is the verb 'suggest' ditransitive? *"He suggested me that we should go there?"*

Comment: No, that would have to be "He suggested to me that..."

Comment: Here is a page that includes a list of some ditransitive verbs, with examples of usage. https://tinyurl.com/y8hpz695         A google search for "ditransitive" will show other lists as well.

Answer (score -1):

"He proposed me that we should go there." is correct

To is optional here?

Yes.

> He proposed to me

is used for asking marry me

> He proposed me

is someone suggesting something

Both statements grammar correct but avoid to for offering

Comment: No: _He proposed me_ is someone putting another person forward as a candidate.